# Template referring to child class within parent class

Tags: oop, d

In D, is it possible to refer to a child (inheriting) class from within a parent class?

I tried something like this:

```
abstract public @property typeof(this)[] sequence();
```

hoping that `typeof(this)` would resolve to the child class that overrides that method instead of the parent class; but it does not. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a bunch of child classes, and a list containing all of them with type of the base class, what would you expect `sequence` to return for each element? A different type for each? That's not how static typing works. Though you may be able to get what you want using standard polymorphism means.

What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I want to do, but for the sake of explanation, it works:

Say I want an abstract class like SerializedElement, from which XMLElement and JSONElement inherits. I would like each child class to have a method / property for returning the child elements, which, obviously would be of the same class. How would I (if this is even possible) implement an abstract method in SerializedElement that returns an array of whatever type the child is (XMLElement or JSONElement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking for [template this parameters](https://dlang.org/spec/template.html#TemplateThisParameter).

```
class Base { T[] sequence(this T)() { return null; } }
class Derived : Base {}
static assert(is(typeof((new Derived).sequence()) == Derived[]));
```

Note, however, that `sequence` above is not a virtual function, and also that the template is instantiated in the context of the base class. To provide a simple interface to the user, you would likely want to forward to a specialized function. This can either be a virtual function (in which case you will need to cast the return value of the function), or a duck-typed function in the subclass:

```
class Base {
    T[] sequence(this T)() {
        // Virtual call, requires unsafe cast of return type.
        return cast(T[])sequenceImplVirtual();
        // Non-virtual call, requires safe cast of this reference
        // and will fail if the subclass doesn't implement it correctly.
        return (cast(T)this).sequenceImplDuck();
    }
    abstract Base[] sequenceImplVirtual();
}

class Derived : Base {
    Derived[] sequenceImplDuck() {
        return [this];
    }
    override Base[] sequenceImplVirtual() {
        return [this];
    }
}

unittest {
    Derived[] arr = (new Derived).sequence;
}
```

The virtual call might seem most alluring, as it gives a compile error if the subclass fails to implement `sequenceImplVirtual`. Note however, that the overriding function doesn't claim to return a `Derived[]`, and if by mistake you return a `Base` or other class that's not derived from `Derived` the program will segfault. The explicit cast effectively hides this. A slightly more verbose program could test this:

```
T[] sequence(this T)() {
    import std.algorithm.searching : all;
    auto result = sequenceImplVirtual();
    assert(result.all!((Base a) => a is null || cast(T)a !is null));
    return cast(T[])result;
}
```

This will give an easy-to-understand assert error at runtime if `sequenceImplVirtual` returns an invalid value.

The duck-typed solution on the other hand, gives no indication that you've forgotten to implement `sequenceImplDuck` until you use it. However, due to it only doing a safe cast (`cast(T)this`), the compiler guarantees that the return value is indeed a `Derived[]`:

```
class Base {
    T[] sequence(this T)() {
        return (cast(T)this).sequenceImplDuck();
    }
}

class Derived : Base {
    // Note: wrong return type.
    // Will fail to compile when you call sequence().
    Base[] sequenceImplDuck() {
        return [this];
    }
}

class Derived2 : Base {
    // Note: No implementation.
    // Will fail to compile when you call sequence().
}

unittest {
    Derived[] arr = (new Derived).sequence;
    auto d = new Derived2;
    auto arr2 = d.sequence;
}
```

The above will fail when compiled with `-unittest`, but if you comment out the unittest, or compile without `-unittest`, the compiler will give no indication that `Derived` or `Derived2` don't implement the needed function correctly, which the virtual call will.